# Flutter: Get data back from StatefulWidget child class to parent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'm new to flutter.

I have a page (Stateful Widget) in the app with a lot of widgets in a column. To improve the code readability, I took some widgets, and made them into seperate classes. For example, I made my dropdownmenu widget, into its only class, like this:

```
class DropDownMenuWidget extends StatefulWidget {


  
  DropDownMenuWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownMenuWidgetState createState() => _DropDownMenuWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _DropDownMenuWidgetState extends State<DropDownMenuWidget> {



  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 20,

      ),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: MASLULIM
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in the parent class, I display the widget like this:

```
DropDownMenuWidget(),
```

However, the problem is, when the user clicks on a item, I can only retrieve that value from the DropDownMenu class, and there the setState() method is called. However, I need to read this value in the parent class. How can I get it there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating your `dropdownValue` variable in your Widget, you can get it from the parent Widget as following with the help of `ValueNotifier`

```
class DropDownMenuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ValueNotifier dropdownValueNotifier;
  DropDownMenuWidget(this.dropdownValueNotifier, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownMenuWidgetState createState() => _DropDownMenuWidgetState();
}

class _DropDownMenuWidgetState extends State<DropDownMenuWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: widget.dropdownValueNotifier,
      builder: (context, dropdownValue, _) {
        return DropdownButton<String>(

          value: dropdownValue,

          // ...

          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            // simply change the value. You dont need setState anymore
            widget.dropdownValueNotifier.value = newValue;
          },

          // ...
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In the parent Widget, create the variable and pass it like this

```
ValueNotifier dropdownValueNotifier = ValueNotifier('One');

// ...

DropDownMenuWidget(dropdownValueNotifier),
```

Comment: Thats how I get the variabe to the widget, but how do I get it back to the parent when the user selects one? Thanks

Comment: Firstly, create the variable in the parent widget, then pass it to the children by parameter. As you can see it above

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but then the user will choose a different value in the widget, and need that value to be read by the parent

Comment: A better approach for this is to use `ValueNotifier`

Comment: Check the new solution

Comment: At this line:  value: dropdownValue. I get the error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'

Comment: Just change it to `value: dropdownValue.toString()`

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your great help!

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use **[typedef](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_typedef.htm)**

First in a separate DrobDown menu you can create the following icon outside of the class:

```
typedef OnItemSelectedDropDown = Function (String value);
```

Now you can apply this thing as follows :

```
class DropDownMenuWidget extends StatefulWidget {

   final OnItemSelectedDropDown onItemSelected ;

  DropDownMenuWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownMenuWidgetState createState() => _DropDownMenuWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _DropDownMenuWidgetState extends State<DropDownMenuWidget> {



  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 20,

      ),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onChanged: (String value) {
        //This line return Value
        widget.onItemSelected.call(value);
      },
      items: MASLULIM
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

When calling the class `DropDownMenuWidget`, it is called as follows on another screen:

```
String dropdownValue ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DropDown Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'New Value DropDown : $dropdownValue',
            ),
            DropDownMenuWidget(
                onItemSelected :(newValue){
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue ;
                  });
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```